# Apps Script- OnChange function triggering 4 times

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

Data is inserted in my spreadsheet via a post action.
upon the arrival of the data. Usually targeting a row ,i want a script to be executed, however the script is executing 4 times.
Tried to see whether the post action was writing the data in several delay however even when i change the onChange function to onEdit function and personally made a change to **ONE** cell to trigger the script manually , it is still executing 4 times.

```
function onChange(){
    createAndSendDocument();
}
```

Comment: I'd try adding if(e.changeType == "WHATEVER" [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)

Comment: Your project might have multiple triggers, delete all of them and create again the one that you need. If you need further help add a [mcve].